# merge multiple tables in Hive SQL

Tags: sql, merge, hive

I have two original tables: product table and component tables

[image]

[image]

Firstly, I need to do an inner merge between these two tables, then create a new table called T1:

```
select a.Product, a.Plant, b.component, b.position, b.valid_date from Product a
inner join component b on a.Product=b.Product
where a.Plant='A'
```

The result T1 looks like in the following way:

[image]

Furthermore, I need to create a new table named T2 based on T1

```
select T1.Product, T1.Plant,T1.position,max(T1.valid_date) as valid_date from T1
Where T1.Plant='A'
Group by T1.Product, T1.Plant,T1.position
```

The result T2 is:

[image]

Finally, I want to merge T1 and T2 based on Product, Plant, position, and valid_date for a final table:

```
select T2.Product, T2.Plant,T1.Component, T2.position, T2.valid_date from T1
INNER JOIN T2 on T1.Product=T2.Product and T1.Plant=T2.Plant and T1.position=T2.position and T1.valid_date=T2.valid_date
where T1.Plant='A'
```

The final table:

[image]

I know this whole process can be done in one hive SQL script. I am confused with multiple tables in one query. I appreciate someone can help me for that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

isn't it that you just want to do this?

```
select
    a.Plant,b.Product,b.position,b.component,
    max(valid_date) as valid_date
from Product a
inner join component b on a.Product = b.Product
where a.Plant = 'A'
group by a.Plant,b.Product,b.position,b.component
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e7ee766ef115d80a901980a0d6f14834)*

the query above produces what you show in output , but based on your comment , I think this is what you are looking for :

```
select t.Plant,t.Product,t.position,t.component, max(t.valid_date) valid_date
( 
select
    b.Product, a.Plant,b.component,b.position,max(valid_date) over (partition by a.Plant,b.Product,b.position) as valid_date
from Product a
join component b on a.Product = b.Product
where a.Plant = 'A'
) t
group by t.Plant,t.Product,t.position,t.component;
```

Comment: @QianruSong , this query is showing component column , not sure what you mean

Comment: To get the T2 is to maximize the date based on the variables except the component. Later, merging T1 and T2 is to bring component back to build the final table.  It has to be 2 selects in one query.

Comment: @QianruSong this is producing exactly what you show us in the output. in your final output , the vbaliddate is different for each component for the same plant and product

Comment: Is it a double MAX? valid_date is not recognized as a valid column.

Comment: @QianruSong ,hmm so it doesn't work in hive! see updated query

Comment: There is only one max by product, plant and position. Also max.. over (partition by...) may not work for HIVE SQL, as my variable evaluated by max is not recognized as a valid column.